# lost "this" in callback from tinymce

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

I have an angular2 app with tinyMce as a HTML editor. The only problem is, I need to convert the URLs in the html through my REST API. To do that I attempted to use "urlconverter_callback" from tinyMce, but I loose the reference to this and get stuck:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('tinymce');
    tinymce.init({
        selector: `[data-tinymce-uniqueid=${this.uniqueId}]`,
    theme: "modern",
    skin: 'light',
    height: 768,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | code',
    plugins: 'code',
        schema: 'html5',
    urlconverter_callback: this.urlConverter,
        setup: ed => {
            ed.on('init', ed2 => {
                if (this.innerValue) ed2.target.setContent(this.innerValue.text);
                this.init = true;
            });
        }
    });

    // I chose to send an update on blur, you may choose otherwise
    tinymce.activeEditor.on('blur', () => this.updateValue());
}

urlConverter(url, node, on_save): string {
    console.log("TinyDirective.urlConverter(%o, %o, %o)", url, node, on_save);
    console.log("TinyDirective.urlConverter: this = %o", this);
    console.log("TinyDirective.urlConverter: this.innerValue = %o", this.innerValue);
    return this.innerValue.url_converter(url);
}
```

From the console I can see, that this is no longer pointing to my directive. As a result I can't access the innerValue property.

How can I create a callback that will have a correct reference of my directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these options:

1) use `bind` within `tinymce.init`

```
urlconverter_callback: this.urlConverter.bind(this)
```

or within constructor:

```
constuctor() {
  this.urlConverter = this.urlConverter.bind(this);
}
```

2) use arrow function on the `urlConverter` method

```
urlConverter = (url, node, on_save): string => {
  ...
}
```

or within `tinymce.init`

```
urlconverter_callback: (url, node, on_save) => this.urlConverter(url, node, on_save)
```

Comment: this was really quick! Thanks a lot! I've ended up using bind within tinymce.init.